# Javascript named function expression, reference error

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, javascript, javascript-objects

I am getting "Reference Error" very randomly (about once in 200 attempts ) with the following code.

```
var securityPrototype = {   
    init: function(){ /* ... */ },
    encryptionKey: function x() {
        var i = x.identifier; 
        return getKey(i);
    }
}

securityPrototype.encryptionKey.identifier = Date.now();

function Security(){}

Security.prototype = securityPrototype;
Security.constructor = Security;

function getKey(){ /* ... */ }

var gate = new Security()
gate.encryptionKey();  // Randomly throws : ReferenceError: x is not defined
```

This code segment lives inside other code but no "eval" is being used , neither the 'with' operator.

I am trying to figure out if due to any condition it is possible to get this error here.

Browser that reproduces this: Chrome on Mac and Windows.
IE and Safari work fine.

Comment: Most likely `Math.random` is your problem since you are getting the error "randomly". Are all values of `Math.random` allowed?

Comment: Had that been the case, we would have got a different error. Actually this is replaceable as I tried to abstract the function.

Comment: Something must be different between the times you get the error and when you don't. Set `securityPrototype.encryptionKey.identifier` to a fix value and see if you still get the error.

Comment: Ok, I have tested to run the code in Chrome in Windows 500 times, and I don't get any error. Is that exactly the code that you use when you get the error?

Comment: @Guffa is almost the same code. The difference is that the value of securityPrototype.encryptionKey.identifier is assigned differently. The main problem is the reference of 'x' inside the encryptionKey method must always be resolved. This function is identical to what I am getting the error.

Comment: Do you get the error sometimes in the same browser instance, or do you get it consistently on some instances on different computers?

Comment: We collect this error in production. Based on the stats, once in 200 attempts we get this. Also, it is only  Chrome Canary or Dev Channel that gives this error. Chrome 38.x

Answer (score 1):

That's because a bug in the implementation of named function expressions, that exists in some versions of some browsers.

In those browsers, two separate function objects are created when you use a named function expression. The property `gate.encryptionKey` is a reference to one function object, and the name `x` is a reference to *a different* function object. They both contain the same code, but they are different instances of the `Function` class.

When you assign a value to `gate.encryptionKey.identifier`, that property is only available in the function object that `gate.encryptionKey` references. The function object that `x` references doesn't have that property.

Simple example of the behaviour in those browsers:

```
var f = function g(){};
f === g; // false

f.expando = 'foo';
g.expando; // undefined
```

This example (example #3) was taken from the page [Named function expressions demystified](http://kangax.github.io/nfe/), where you can read more about named function expressions, and the implementation bugs.

Comment: This code will give Reference error since 'g' is not defined outside the scope of g's definition.

Comment: var f = function g(){
  console.log( g===f);
  
 };
f() // returns true

Comment: @sbr: Yes, in a browser that implements named function expressions correctly, using `g` outside the function *should* give a reference error. Browsers that doesn't implement it correctly generally also have the bug that the identifier leaks outside the scope of the function. See example #1 on the page that I linked to.

Comment: thanks. That link is great. Though I am wondering if the browser implementation is wrong , the above code would have failed always .

Comment: @sbr: The implementation is only wrong in some versions of some browsers. Older versions of IE for example has those bugs.